# Stop users from logging in from multiple locations

Tags: login, membership, limit

We are running a membership site. However, we have a problem with users that subscribe to our content that are sharing there login information with other people, circumventing the need for those users to also need a subscription. Any ideas for plugins that already do this? Or suggestions of how to go about logging people out that login from 2 locations? I assume some use of IP addresses per login or something...?

Answer (score 2):

We had a similar problem where we needed to give access to partners and "membership" or "subscription" plugins seemed to offer what we needed.  The problem we had was that the plugins we found were all for-pay, not free or freemium.

Understanding this, the MagicMembers and aMember Pro plugins both had functions that could prevent access sharing.  I'm sure there were others, but the spreadsheet I used to compare the different products (and a quick check of each site) turned up these two as explicitly doing what you need.

The costs of these can range a great deal. I'd suggest searching with terms like "wordpress subscription access sharing" and seeing what turns up.  "Access sharing" is what most of the plugin developers called the situation you are describing...so that might also help.

Comment: Can you define "where" in MagicMember you can see or set this option? I've used it, in fact, using it on this project I'm asking about but it didn't seem to provide any such thing. :(

Comment: We did our research and basic testing more than eight months ago.  Looking at the MagicMember website, it looks like you need their "Magic Kicker" plug-in to block login sharing. Not sure if that's been the case all along or if it was a recent change.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/s2member/)

This plugin already does this your requirement.

Comment: [An answer should be more than just a link to an external site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion). Please add a solution.

Comment: Like above, can you define where it has this feature? How does it work?